# Remove values from a dataset based on a vector of those values

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this, except it's much longer and with many more values:

```
dataset <- data.frame(grps = c("a","b","c","a","d","b","c","a","d","b","c","a"), response = c(1,4,2,6,4,7,8,9,4,5,0,3))
```

In R, I would like to remove all rows containing the values "b" or "c" using a vector of values to remove, i.e.

```
remove<-c("b","c")
```

The actual dataset is very long with many hundreds of values to remove, so removing values one-by-one would be very time consuming.

Comment: FYI: Try not to use the term "factor" in this way. (You did this in your previous question too.) 'Factor' means something very specific in R, and this isn't it. Type `?factor` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
dataset[!(dataset$grps %in% remove),]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also `subset`:

```
subset(dataset, !(grps %in% remove))
```

... which is really just a wrapper around `[` that lets you skip writing `dataset$` over and over when there are multiple subset criteria.  But, as the help page warns:

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
>   ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.

I've never had any problems, but the majority of my R code is scripting for my own use with relatively static inputs.

---

2013-04-12

I have now had problems. If you're building a package for CRAN, `R CMD check` will throw a NOTE if you have use `subset` in this way in your code - it will wonder if `grps` is a global variable, even though `subset` is evaluating it within `dataset`'s environment (not the global one). So if there's any possiblity your code will end up in a package and you feel squeamish about NOTEs, stick with Rcoster's method.